# How do you say "A tight community"

Tags: vocabulary

Helo All! 
I"m trying to figure out a good translation for "a tight community". For example, I'm trying to say 
"A tight community is not a means of having a good  student organization, but the end goal of a student club"  － how could I
express that？

Comment: it would seem a simple matter to find the answer by searching the web：
iciba has： tight－knit with ５ example sentences involving tight－knit community（twice），tight - knit bands，tight - knit family，tight - knit and cohesive unit：

Comment: @S.Rhee yes, it should be tight-knit/tightly-knit. Though ... given the forum, isn't OP asking how to express that _in Chinese_? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: iciba=爱词霸(http://www.iciba.com)

Comment: comment #1 refers to translations available at "iciba", an online C-E-C dictionary as of Sept 24'14,(with drastic volume reduction at iciba no longer available)

Comment: in view of iciba's contraction, note that feeding "tight-knit,tightly-knit(sic),tightly knit" to jukuu will still supply translations contained in answers below: 2. 紧密结合在一起的(同族 homogeneous)社会 (society), 4.紧凑的商业文化 (business culture), tightly knit: 2 of 6 relevant,tightly-knit (sic) 1.紧密型企业集团 (groups of enterprises), besides there should not be any problem finding translation of "community"

Answer (score 2):

团结的社区

团结:

1. [local civil corps]∶唐宋时地方民兵丁壮组织。亦指该类组织的士兵
2. [harmony;friendship]∶和睦；友好；安定；团结
3. [unite;rally;close]∶联合起来以完成共同目标团结一致
4. [aggregate]∶指分散物聚拢成团;聚合 反义词：分裂

http://baike.baidu.com/subview/27127/5038298.htm

Comment: 紧密团结的社区

tight -> 紧密

Comment: @XiaogeSu, better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

First,I would make sure I understand what you want to express.

Do you mean "A tight community” is one in which students have much communication,much relation to each other and engage in many community acitvities?

If my understanding was right,In Chinese"A tight community" could be expressed as "紧密的团体"

.In Chinese,you could express the whole sentence as"紧密的团体不是实现优秀的学生组织的途径，而是学生组织的最终目标".

---

I'am Chinese,if I have made any mistakes in English or written something makes you confused,please correct me.I will be appreciate and happy to discuss with you. :-)

Comment: I do not think you can use 紧密 to decorate 团体。

Answer (score 0):

关系密切的社群 will be an alternative translation ?